# Get column ID of element in loop

Tags: python, loops

Im trying to create a function that will transform a regular Matrix into CSR form (I don't want to use the scipy.sparse one).

To do this, I'm using a nested for-loop to run through a given matrix to create a new matrix with three rows.
The first row ('Values') should contain all non-zero values. The second ('Cols') should contain the column index for each number in 'Values'. The third row should contain the index value in 'Values' for the first non-zero value on each row.

My question regards the second and third rows:
Is there a way of getting the column ID for the element 'i' in the for-loop?

```
M=array([[4,0,39],
        [0,5,0],
        [0,0,7]])

def Convert(x):
    
    CSRMatrix = []
    Values = []
    Cols = []
    Rows = []
    
    for k in x:
        
        for i in k:
        
            if i != 0:
                
                    Values.append(i)
                    Cols.append({#the column index value of 'i'})
                    Rows.append[#theindex in 'Values' of the first non-zero element on each row]
                    
    CSRMatrix.append(Values)
    CSRMatrix.append(Cols)
    CSRMatrix.append(Rows)
    
    return(CSRMatrix)

Convert(M)
```

Comment: You maybe need [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate). If it is a numpy array, please use `x.nonzero()` directly.

Comment: Wow @MechanicPig the nonzero() function simplifies the whole thing a lot. Do you think it can also solve the task on the third row (Rows.append) ?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you can refer to the answer I just released.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you want exactly for `Cols.append()` because of the way you commented it in the code between curly braces.

Is it a dict containing the index:value of all non 0 value? Or a list of sets containing the indexes of all non 0 values (which would be weird), or is it all the indexes of each row in your array?

Anyway I put the 2 most likely candidates (dict and list of indexes for each row) test each one and delete the unwanted one and if none are right please add some more specifics:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[4,0,39],
     [0,5,0],
     [0,0,7]])

def Convert(x):
    
    CSRMatrix = []
    Values = []
    Cols = []
    Rows = []
    
    for num in x:
        for i in range(len(num)):
            if num[i] != 0:
                Values.append(num[i])
                Cols.append({i:num[i]}) # <- if dict. Remove if not what you wanted
                Rows.append(i)
            Cols.append(i) # <- list of all indexes in the array for each row. Remove if not what you wanted                    

    CSRMatrix.append(Values)
    CSRMatrix.append(Cols)
    CSRMatrix.append(Rows)
    return(CSRMatrix)

x = Convert(m)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

enumerate() passes an index for every iteration.
Thereby the second row can be easily created by appending *num2*.
For the third row you have to check again if you have already added a value in that row. If not append *num2* and set the *non_zero* check to False. For the next row *non_zero* check is set to True again.

```
def Convert(x):
 
     CSRMatrix = []
     Values = []
     Cols = []
     Rows = []
     for num, k in enumerate(x):
         non_zero = True
         for num2, i in enumerate(k):
             if i != 0:
 
                 Values.append(i)
                 Cols.append(num2)
                 if non_zero:
                     Rows.append(num2)
                     non_zero = False
 
     CSRMatrix.append(Values)
     CSRMatrix.append(Cols)
     CSRMatrix.append(Rows)
 
     return (CSRMatrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a numpythonic implementation, use the `nonzero` method to directly obtain the row and column index of non-zero elements, and then use a comparison to generate a mask. Finally, use `nonzero` for the mask to get the row indices:

```py
>>> M = np.array([[ 4,  0, 39],
...               [ 0,  5,  0],
...               [ 0,  0,  7]])
>>> r, c = M.nonzero()
>>> mask = np.concatenate(([True], r[1:] != r[:-1]))
>>> [M[r, c], c, *mask.nonzero()]
[array([ 4, 39,  5,  7]), array([0, 2, 1, 2]), array([0, 2, 3])]
```

Test of a larger array:

```py
>>> a = np.random.choice(10, size=(8, 8), p=[0.73] + [0.03] * 9)
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 9, 0],
       [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]])
>>> r, c = a.nonzero()
>>> mask = np.concatenate(([True], r[1:] != r[:-1]))
>>> pp([a[r, c], c, *mask.nonzero()])
[array([8, 1, 1, 5, 4, 9, 9, 1, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9, 4]),
 array([4, 7, 0, 2, 3, 6, 2, 7, 3, 4, 7, 2, 5, 1, 7, 7, 1, 5], dtype=int64),
 array([ 0,  2,  6,  8, 11, 13, 15, 16], dtype=int64)]
```

Comment: If I change r and c around, then the first two arrays come out right. The third one doesn't though. For matrix M, the third array should should be (0,2,3), as those are the indexes in the first array of the numbers (4,5,7) that are first on a new row. Should the mask be modified in some way?

Comment: @Bronze Please check the current code, which should match your description.

Comment: You, sir, are an absolute star. Immensely grateful. May I ask a last question? I'm struggling to understand how the mask works. How does the 'True' statement combine with the slicings?

Comment: @Bronze This is actually very easy to understand. Try printing `(r[1:] != r[:-1]).nonzero()[0]`, and you will find that this is the index of the last occurrence of each type of number in `r`(but without last type of number). If you add 1 for them and add a `0` at the front of the array, this is the index of the first occurrence of each type of number. Instead of choosing this method, I add a `True` in front of `r[1:] != r[:-1]` and then use `nonzero`. The effect of both is the same.